# Using epiphany-browser via a remote xdmcp session

Tags: xubuntu, webkit, epiphany, xdmcp

`Epiphany-browser` works fine when I am on my physical machine running Xubuntu 22.04, however when remotely accessing the machine via an `xdcp` connection using `vcxsrv` I get the following error message:

```
(WebKitWebProcess:2): Gdk-ERROR **: 17:14:25.307: The program 'WebKitWebProcess' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'GLXBadFBConfig'.
  (Details: serial 174 error_code 163 request_code 149 (GLX) minor_code 21)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

(epiphany:115286): epiphany-WARNING **: 17:14:25.386: Web process crashed
```

I am not sure what this is referring to, unfortunately.

Comment: Is vcxsrv configured to use indirect rendering? See for example [Can't run OpenGL on WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66506098/4440445)

Comment: 'WebKitWebProcess' is  trying to open a connection to an X Window (or equivalent) display manager,  pointed to by the `DISPLAY` environment variable. Your `XRDP` connection is not providing this.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your comment. The `Native opengl` has always been ticked by default for me when using vcxsrv, but I'd never added the environment variable to my `~/.bashrc` file, mainly because I didn't know what it was about. I followed the steps in your provided link, and added: `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0` it seems to have done the trick, but will need to test further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by `@steeldriver`. I believe the following steps have resolved my issue.

1. Edit the `~/.bashrc` file and add the line: `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0` to the bottom of the file.

[image: Contents of .bashrc file]

2. Restarted my machine (a logout would probably be enough).
3. The opened `vcxsrv` and made sure the following options were ticked:

[image: Options selected in the vcxsrv window]

4. Once logged in I was able to `epiphany-browser` without issue in the `vcxsrv` session.

[image: Successful loading of epiphany-browser]

Original Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66506098/4440445

I hope this information will be of use to others.